# Avoid casting to access specialized member of a derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

In our code, we have a physical problem (to be solved) which encapsulates a medium (fluid or solid for example).

A problem can be of several types (heat conduction, turbulent flow, ...), all deriving from a base class, and encapsulates consequently a medium of different nature (e.g. "turbulent flow" type of problems are solved on fluids). All media inherits from an abstract base class.

What is the elegant way to **deal with both inheritances** (problem/medium) **and encapsulation**? Notably can I **avoid repeatidly using static-casts** everytime I need to access specific functionalities of the derived medium class in a derived problem?

A simplified illustrative version of the code:

```
class ProblemAbstract
{
public: 
  virtual void solve() = 0;
...

protected:
  MediumAbstract * med;
};


class ProblemTurbulent: public ProblemAbstract
{
  // ProblemTurbulent is always built with a MediumFluid
  ...

  virtual void solve()
  {
    // Can I avoid this?
    MediumFluid * med_f = static_cast<MediumFluid>(med);  // MediumFluid derives from MediumAbstract
    med_s->someSpecificFluidMethod();
  }
};
```

Comment: you code example seems ok to me, I see no problem with the casting as long as you make sure you cast to the right type. another solution is not keeping any pointer in the base class and make derived class get some `Context` pointer on which they work on, but you example seems leaner and safer

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` to cast an abstract to an implementation which add some controls

Comment: Also, instead of repeating `xxx_cast` each time, use a getter in your implementation which do the cast : `MediumFuild* getMed() { /* return cast */}` and use it to retrieve data : `MediumFuild * med_f = getMed()`

Comment: The only way to avoid the casting would be to set this up using templates as a concept, and avoid the inheritance all together

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the visitor design pattern [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Thanks all - template is not option, code is meant to be seen and modified by unexperienced programmers.

Comment: @Garf365  I like your simple solution. Would covariance work in that case (i.e. having a getMed() returning a different type in each Problem sub-class) ?

Comment: because `getMedium` is only an implementation need and it's only defined in implementations as non virtual function, there is no problem. Each implementation can have any non virtual function it needs, without any regards on other implementation, depending on its own needs. I hope I am clear

Answer (score 1):

I think that little template will not hurt anyone, even unexperienced programmers

```
class ProblemAbstract
{
public: 
  virtual void solve() = 0;
...

protected:
  MediumAbstract * med;
};

template <typename MediumTypeT>
class ProblemHelper :
    public ProblemAbstract
{    
protected:
    MediumTypeT getMedium()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<MediumTypeT *>(med);
    }
};

class ProblemTurbulent : 
    public ProblemHelper<MediumFluid>
{
  // ProblemTurbulent is always built with a MediumFluid
  ...

  virtual void solve()
  {
    getMedium()->someSpecificFluidMethod();
  }
};
```